# What is the best way to count words in C?

Tags: c, algorithm

Here is a simple count word program, which i feel is very efficient. Is this the best way  to count words in C, or are there any flaws in this program?

```
         #include <stdio.h>
         int CountWords(void);
         main()
         {
            printf("count the words and enter string\n");
            CountWords();

         }
        int CountWords(void)
        {
            char c;
            int num=0;
            int flag= 0;
             while((c=getchar())!='\n')
            {
              if(c==' ')
              {
                flag=0 ;        
              }                         
              else if(flag==0)
              {
                num++;
                flag=1;     
              }                      
           }
              printf("Num is %d",num);
         }
```

Comment: More efficient and better than what?

Comment: Sorry... not a question.

Comment: Considering you asked this question this morning (German time) and it was bashed and deleted (without proper reason, in my opinion), I don't dare to hope this one will have a better fate.

Comment: Better than the normal one or is there any other better way??

Comment: More efficient and better than what?

Comment: I really dont understand y it got deleted???

Comment: Normal one? The one in K&R? If that's what you mean, no, it's pretty similar at first glance, just less elegant.

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask for general code reviews.  That being said, you're counting groups of nonspace characters separated by space characters.  While you might want to consider "military-industrial" as one word, dialog like "Yes--I'll be there" should probably be 4 words, not 3.  An ellipsis will usually be written as "foo ... bar" or "foo...bar", neither of which you'll count as two words.

Comment: Personally, I think a request for a code-review is fair enough. There are enough questions which amount to, "why is this crashing?", which are just as specific to the questioner's own code. SOers usually love criticising other people's code, but apparently if you actually ask them to, it's another matter ;-)

Comment: Why on earth was this closed?  This *is* a real question... I wish SO wouldn't be *completely* run by managers and students... or maybe it's time to create a SegmentationFault website for people actually interested in code review, mathematics? Hint! :)

Comment: **one function is hardly a code review! this is a legit question.**

Comment: You might want to look at some open source implementations of wc, e.g. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/wc.c, http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/head/usr.bin/wc/wc.c?view=markup and http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/wc/wc.c?only_with_tag=MAIN&view=markup.

Comment: I just wann share what i could do something on this word count.Thanks everyone forthe support.

Answer (score 3):

Your count will be off by one with this program. This is because you are checking for a space to add one to your count of words. What do you think will happen with the last word in the string?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I can think of is that it will count punctuation marks as words if they are surrounded by spaces.

E.g.

```
The quick - and lazy - fox.
```

will be reported as containing 7 words although there are only 5.
You may want to reduce the set of word characters to alphanumeric characters only, and counting punctuation marks as word separators - unless it is a ' or a - in the middle of a word, depending on what you define as a word (are *it's* and *quick-witted* single words ? Two words each ?).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `flag=1` and the off by one error should go away.

Comment: empty string and word count=1

Answer (score 0):

Define your problem in terms of an algorithm first. For example, make a flow chart. Run some quick examples through your logic, just as other posters have done. Do all this **before you write code**.

Then, once you think you have the best algorithm, write that in C.

Come up with a list of questions to ask yourself, such as "What is a word?", "What is not a word?".

For parsing text, or tokens of any kind, you may be interested in expressing your ideas in terms of [Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form). Take a look at any computer language specification, and notice how they define something like an identifier. Even if you don't use this to write your program, it should help you think out the problem.

Are words restricted to alphabetic characters a-z and A-Z? What about hyphenated words?

Perhaps (not in formal BNF):

hyphen := '-'
alpha := 'a' | 'b' | ... | 'z' | 'A' | 'B' | ... | 'Z'
alphagroup := alpha | alpha alphagroup
hyphenword := alphagroup hyphen alphagroup | alphagroup hyphen hyphenword
word := alphagroup | hyphenword

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full piece of code that can improve that program and which works in all conditions:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
         void CountWords(void);
         void main()
         {
            printf("\n\tcount the words and enter string\n\n\n");
            CountWords();

         }
        void CountWords(void)
        {
            char c;
            int num=0;
            int flag= 0;
             while((c=getchar())!='\n')
            {
            if((c==' ')||(c=='  ')||(c=='.')||(c==';')||(c==',')||(c==';')
                ||(c==':')||(c=='"')||(c=='?')||(c=='!')||(c=='-'))
              {
                flag=0 ;        
              }                         
              else if(flag==0)
              {
                num++;
                flag=1;     
              }

           }
              printf("\t\n\n\nNumber of words is %d\n",num);
         }

/*By Md. azaz*/
```

Answer (score 0):

bah. Way too much code:

```
int numwords(char *str)
{   int n = 0;
    for(str=strtok(str, " -.!,;"); str; str=strtok(NULL, " -.!,;"))
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

is a blatant way to count words in c. libc `strtok()` is highly optimized.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main()
{
 char str[SIZE]={ '\0' };
 int string_size;
 int wordcount, found=0, other=0;

 printf("Enter the string:");
 fgets(str, SIZE, stdin);

 string_size = strlen(str);

 for(int i=0;i<=string_size;i++)
 {
  if(isalnum(str[i]) && !isalnum(str[i-1]))
    found++;
 }

 printf("Number of words are:%d\n", found);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: some explanation would be useful!