# Count lines, words and characters in C

Tags: c

Below is my function to count number of lines, words and characters -

```
void count(char* file) {

int fd;
long end=0;
char c;
long words=0;
long lines=0;

if((fd=open(file, O_RDONLY))>0){
    end=lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(read(fd, &c, 1)==1){
        if(c == ' ')
            words++;
        if(c == '\n') {
            lines++;
            words++;
        }
    }

    printf("The Number of characters in file is: %ld\n",end);   
    printf("The Number of lines in file is: %ld\n",lines);
    printf("The Number of words in file is: %ld\n",words);

    close(fd);
}
else{
    printf("Error: ",strerror(errno));
}
}
```

I am getting right on number of lines and characters, but wrong on number of words. As you see i am counting number of spaces, if there are multiple spaces, how to count words(I don't want to use f* functions, like fscanf with filepointer) ? How does wc command handle this ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a lexer such as lex for this task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to count words in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109943/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-words-in-c)

Comment: FYI - I agree the above code is buggy, given that there are holes in file, the character count turns wrong(then even wc command is wrong with holes in file ;) ), but anyway i resolved it, i am worried about words.

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use `strpbrk()` standard libc function? Do some thing alse:

```
    char keys[] = " \n";
    ...
    while( expression ){

        ret = read(fd, buf, BUF_LEN - 1);

        if (ret == -1)
            /*do errno*/
        else if ( ret ) {

            char* p = buf;
            buf[ ret ] = '\0';

            while( (p = strpbrk(p, keys)) ) {
                if (*p == key[1])
                    ++lines;
                ++words;
                ++p;
            }
        }
        else
            /* do close file */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that this could be handled. One might be to use a boolean flag to indicate whether the last character was a space character or not. Then you only update the words counter if the current character is a space *and* the last character was *not* a space, etc.

Comment: I got what you said (that was even my natural guess earlier, but had forgotten '\t') put it -

   if(c == ' '){
    if(prevchar != ' ' || prevchar != '\t')
     words++;
   }

but that didn't made much difference when i run it(even with check for '\t'), so removed the extra code

./Run -f Queue.c 
The Number of characters in file is: 1326
The Number of lines in file is: 100
The Number of words in file is: 189
Same with wc command gives
wc Queue.c 
100  171 1326 Queue.c

So was wondering how wc command works, and how i am doing different

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that doesn't look quite right. What happens if there are multiple spaces between words? Also, what happens if words are separated by tabs or newline characters?

Instead, you should track the state. And you should be checking for whitespace characters is general with `isspace()`. When you hit a character that is not whitespace, set IsInWord = true. Then, when you hit a whitespace character set IsInWord = false. But first count the word when you hit the whitespace character AND IsInWord is true.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple state machine for words and one for lines.  (Your line count can be wrong, too.  For example, what if the last line doesn't have a `'\n'`?)

Your word state machine needs to states:  (1) between words and (2) inside a word.  If you get a non-space while in state 1, transition to state 2 and increment your counter.  When you get a space while in state 2, transition back to state 1.

Comment: Just did this, vi 2 and entered hello and saved, when i see with od command this is what it shows:  od -c 2
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006

Comment: On my Ubuntu system I was getting a different linecount than wc and it turned out that wc was apparently not counting the last line of the file if it didn't end in '\n'

Comment: @Cleonjoys I was trying to create a file that ended without a carriage return in a text editor and was having trouble doing it. It seems like they will automatically add the carriage return even if you don't. I ended up writing a small program to do it.